# Can YAWS run in multi-machine mode?

Tags: yaws

I know Erlang has the ability to run across multiple machines. Can YAWS also do this? Would there be any advantage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes yaws can.  One might do this for simple distribution reasons.  Distributing yaws across multiple servers reduces SPOFs, reduces potential performance bottlenecks, etc. (like having any web server across multiple servers would do).

Comment: BTW, do you know how one would setup YAWS in a distributed mode?

Comment: Look at the name and sname tokens if i recall.